# Kendo Mvc Grid - Filter Cell template and style

Tags: templates, model-view-controller, filter, kendo-ui, grid

**Scenario:**

I would like to change template and style for my Dropdown in Filter in Kendo Grid. In my project, there is already dropdown done as I would like it to have, but it is single dropdown in modal window:
**Code:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("StatusId")
    .DataValueField("id")
    .DataTextField("name")
        .Events(e =>
        {
            e.Change("statusChanged");
            e.Select("statusSelect");
            e.DataBound("statusDataBound");
        })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => read.Action("ReadOrderStatuses", "OrderData"))
    )
    .Template("# if(data.disabled){# <span class='k-state-default tbd'><p>#: data.name #</p></span> # } else { # <span class='k-state-default selectableItem'><p>#: data.name #</p></span># } # ")
)
```

**Problem:**
 I would like to get the same effect in dropdown in Filter Cell in my Grid. I have written code:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.StatusId)
    .Title(Resx.Grid_Status)
    .ClientTemplate("<div class='editable-field'>#= Status #   #= StatusChangeDate #</div>")
    .EditorTemplateName("OrderStateEditor")
    .Filterable(filterable => filterable
        .Cell(configurator =>
        {
             configurator.Template("# if(data.disabled){# <span class='k-state-default tbd'><p>#: data.name #</p></span> # } else { # <span class='k-state-default'><p>#: data.name #</p></span># } #");
        }).UI("statusFilter").Extra(false)
    )
    .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { data_column_data_type = "dropdownlist", data_dropdown_url = "/Admin/OrderData/ReadOrderStatuses" });
```

**Effect**

Unfortunately I get JS error in:

```
configurator.Template("# if(data.disabled){# <span class='k-state-default tbd'><p>#: data.name #</p></span> # } else { # <span class='k-state-default'><p>#: data.name #</p></span># } #");
        })

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.
```

I also tried to do it without # at the beginning and end of template string. But get error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if
```

In my browser it looks like (**** shows error place):

```
    jQuery(function(){jQuery("#orders-grid").kendoGrid({"edit":gridToRefresh,"dataBound":GridHelper.saveGridOptions,"columnResize":GridHelper.saveGridOptions,"columnHide":GridHelper.saveGridOptions,"columnShow":GridHelper.saveGridOptions,"columns":[{"title":"Numer","attributes":{"alwaysShow":"True"},"headerAttributes":{"data-field":"StoreOrderId","data-title":"Numer"},"width":"50px","field":"StoreOrderId","filterable":false,"encoded":true},{"title":"Imię i nazwisko","attributes":{"style":"word-wrap:hyphenate;overflow-wrap:break-word"},"headerAttributes":{"style":"white-space: normal;","data-field":"UserName","data-title":"Imię i nazwisko"},"hidden":true,"field":"UserName","filterable":{"messages":{"info":"Pokaż wiersze o wartościach, które","isTrue":"prawda","isFalse":"fałsz","filter":"Filtr","clear":"Wyczyść filtr","and":"oraz","or":"lub","selectValue":"-Wybierz wartość-","value":"Wartość","cancel":"Anuluj","search":"Szukaj"},"operators":{"string":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","startswith":"zaczynają się od","endswith":"kończą się na","contains":"zawierają","doesnotcontain":"nie zawierają"},"number":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","gte":"są większe lub równe","gt":"są większe niż","lte":"są mniejsze lub równe","lt":"są mniejsze niż"},"date":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","gte":"są późniejsze lub równe","gt":"są późniejsze niż","lte":"są wcześniejsze lub równe","lt":"są wcześniejsze niż"},"enums":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż"}}},"encoded":true},{"title":"E-mail","attributes":{"style":"text-overflow:ellipsis;"},"headerAttributes":{"data-field":"UserEmail","data-title":"E-mail"},"field":"UserEmail","filterable":{"messages":{"info":"Pokaż wiersze o wartościach, które","isTrue":"prawda","isFalse":"fałsz","filter":"Filtr","clear":"Wyczyść filtr","and":"oraz","or":"lub","selectValue":"-Wybierz wartość-","value":"Wartość","cancel":"Anuluj","search":"Szukaj"},"operators":{"string":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","startswith":"zaczynają się od","endswith":"kończą się na","contains":"zawierają","doesnotcontain":"nie zawierają"},"number":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","gte":"są większe lub równe","gt":"są większe niż","lte":"są mniejsze lub równe","lt":"są mniejsze niż"},"date":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","gte":"są późniejsze lub równe","gt":"są późniejsze niż","lte":"są wcześniejsze lub równe","lt":"są wcześniejsze niż"},"enums":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż"}}},"encoded":true},{"title":"Data złożenia","headerAttributes":{"data-column-data-type":"date","data-field":"CreateDate","data-title":"Data złożenia"},"field":"CreateDate","format":"{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss tt}","filterable":{"messages":{"info":"Pokaż wiersze o wartościach, które","isTrue":"prawda","isFalse":"fałsz","filter":"Filtr","clear":"Wyczyść filtr","and":"oraz","or":"lub","selectValue":"-Wybierz wartość-","value":"Wartość","cancel":"Anuluj","search":"Szukaj"},"operators":{"string":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","startswith":"zaczynają się od","endswith":"kończą się na","contains":"zawierają","doesnotcontain":"nie zawierają"},"number":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","gte":"są większe lub równe","gt":"są większe niż","lte":"są mniejsze lub równe","lt":"są mniejsze niż"},"date":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","gte":"są późniejsze lub równe","gt":"są późniejsze niż","lte":"są wcześniejsze lub równe","lt":"są wcześniejsze niż"},"enums":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż"}}},"encoded":true},{"title":"Wartość zamówienia","headerAttributes":{"data-column-data-type":"range","data-field":"ProductsPrice","data-title":"Wartość zamówienia"},"hidden":true,"template":"#= kendo.toString(ProductsPrice,\u0027C2\u0027) #","field":"ProductsPrice","filterable":{"messages":{"info":"Pokaż wiersze o wartościach, które","isTrue":"prawda","isFalse":"fałsz","filter":"Filtr","clear":"Wyczyść filtr","and":"oraz","or":"lub","selectValue":"-Wybierz wartość-","value":"Wartość","cancel":"Anuluj","search":"Szukaj"},"operators":{"string":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","startswith":"zaczynają się od","endswith":"kończą się na","contains":"zawierają","doesnotcontain":"nie zawierają"},"number":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","gte":"są większe lub równe","gt":"są większe niż","lte":"są mniejsze lub równe","lt":"są mniejsze niż"},"date":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","gte":"są późniejsze lub równe","gt":"są późniejsze niż","lte":"są wcześniejsze lub równe","lt":"są wcześniejsze niż"},"enums":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż"}}},"encoded":true},{"title":"Całkowita wartość zamówienia","headerAttributes":{"data-column-data-type":"range","data-field":"TotalPrice","data-title":"Całkowita wartość zamówienia"},"template":"#= kendo.toString(TotalPrice,\u0027C2\u0027) #","field":"TotalPrice","filterable":{"messages":{"info":"Pokaż wiersze o wartościach, które","isTrue":"prawda","isFalse":"fałsz","filter":"Filtr","clear":"Wyczyść filtr","and":"oraz","or":"lub","selectValue":"-Wybierz wartość-","value":"Wartość","cancel":"Anuluj","search":"Szukaj"},"operators":{"string":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","startswith":"zaczynają się od","endswith":"kończą się na","contains":"zawierają","doesnotcontain":"nie zawierają"},"number":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","gte":"są większe lub równe","gt":"są większe niż","lte":"są mniejsze lub równe","lt":"są mniejsze niż"},"date":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","gte":"są późniejsze lub równe","gt":"są późniejsze niż","lte":"są wcześniejsze lub równe","lt":"są wcześniejsze niż"},"enums":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż"}}},"encoded":true},{"title":"Zamówienie opłacone","headerAttributes":{"data-column-data-type":"dropdown","data-dropdown-json":"[{\u0026quot;id\u0026quot;:true,\u0026quot;name\u0026quot;:\u0026quot;Opłacone\u0026quot;},{\u0026quot;id\u0026quot;:false,\u0026quot;name\u0026quot;:\u0026quot;Nieopłacone\u0026quot;}]","data-field":"PaymentCompleted","data-title":"Zamówienie opłacone"},"width":"50px","template":"# if(PaymentCompleted) { # \u003ci class=\u0027fas fa-lg fa-fw fa-check color-success\u0027\u003e\u003c/i\u003e \u003cbr/\u003e #= PaymentDate # #} else {#   # } # ","field":"PaymentCompleted","filterable":{"messages":{"info":"Pokaż tylko","isTrue":"opłacone","isFalse":"nieopłacone","filter":"Filtr","clear":"Wyczyść filtr","and":"oraz","or":"lub","selectValue":"-Wybierz wartość-","value":"Wartość","cancel":"Anuluj","search":"Szukaj"},"operators":{"string":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","startswith":"zaczynają się od","endswith":"kończą się na","contains":"zawierają","doesnotcontain":"nie zawierają"},"number":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","gte":"są większe lub równe","gt":"są większe niż","lte":"są mniejsze lub równe","lt":"są mniejsze niż"},"date":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","gte":"są późniejsze lub równe","gt":"są późniejsze niż","lte":"są wcześniejsze lub równe","lt":"są wcześniejsze niż"},"enums":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż"}}},"encoded":true},{"title":"Sposób dostawy","headerAttributes":{"style":"white-space: normal;","data-field":"DeliveryWayName","data-title":"Sposób dostawy"},"template":"#= DeliveryWayName # #= DeliveryWayName \u0026\u0026 (CanCreatePackage || PackageReferenceNumber) ? \u0027\u003cbr /\u003e\u0027 : \u0027\u0027 ##= CanCreatePackage \u0026\u0026 !PackCancelled ? OrderGridService.createButtonCreatePackage(StoreOrderId, CanCreatePackage, DeliveryType, \u0027Utwórz paczkę\u0027) : \u0027\u0027 # #= !PackCancelled \u0026\u0026 CanCreatePackage \u0026\u0026 PackageReferenceNumber ? \u0027\u003cbr /\u003e\u0027 : \u0027\u0027 #\u003cdiv style=\"text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; width: 100%;\"#= PackageReferenceNumber ? \u0027title=\"\u0027 : \u0027\u0027 # #= PackageReferenceNumber ##= PackageReferenceNumber ? \u0027\"\u0027 : \u0027\u0027 # #= PackageReferenceNumber #\u003e#= PackageReferenceNumber ? \u0027Numer przesyłki: \u0027 : \u0027\u0027 # #= PackageReferenceNumber #\u003c/div\u003e#= !PackCancelled \u0026\u0026 CanGetLabel \u0026\u0026 PackageReferenceNumber ? OrderGridService.createGetLabelButton(PackageReferenceNumber, CanGetLabel, StoreOrderId, DeliveryType, \u0027Pobierz etykietę\u0027) : \u0027\u0027 #","field":"DeliveryWayName","filterable":false,"encoded":true},{"title":"Status","headerAttributes":{"data-column-data-type":"dropdown","data-dropdown-url":"/Admin/OrderData/ReadOrderStatuses","data-field":"StatusId","data-title":"Status"},"template":"\u003cdiv class=\u0027editable-field\u0027\u003e#= Status #   #= StatusChangeDate #\u003c/div\u003e","field":"StatusId","filterable":{"extra":false,"messages":{"info":"Pokaż wiersze o wartościach, które","isTrue":"prawda","isFalse":"fałsz","filter":"Filtr","clear":"Wyczyść filtr","and":"oraz","or":"lub","selectValue":"-Wybierz wartość-","value":"Wartość","cancel":"Anuluj","search":"Szukaj"},"operators":{"string":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","startswith":"zaczynają się od","endswith":"kończą się na","contains":"zawierają","doesnotcontain":"nie zawierają"},"number":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","gte":"są większe lub równe","gt":"są większe niż","lte":"są mniejsze lub równe","lt":"są mniejsze niż"},"date":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","gte":"są późniejsze lub równe","gt":"są późniejsze niż","lte":"są wcześniejsze lub równe","lt":"są wcześniejsze niż"},"enums":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż"}},"ui":statusFilter,

****"cell":{"template":# if(data.disabled){# <span class='k-state-default tbd'><p>#: data.name #</p></span> # } else { # <span class='k-state-default'><p>#: data.name #</p></span># } #}},****

"encoded":true,"editor":"\u003cscript id=\"orderStatusTemplate\" type=\"text/x-kendo-tmpl\"\u003e\r\n    #\r\n    if (data.disabled != null) {#\r\n    \u003cli tabindex=\"-1\" role=\"option\" class=\"tbd k-item\"\u003e${data.name}\u003c/li\u003e\r\n    # } else { #\r\n    \u003cli tabindex=\"-1\" role=\"option\" class=\"k-item\"\u003e${data.name}\u003c/li\u003e\r\n    }#\r\n\u003c/script\u003e\r\n\u003cdiv class=\"order-status\"\u003e\r\n    \u003cinput id=\"StatusId\" name=\"StatusId\" type=\"text\" /\u003e\u003cscript\u003e\r\n\tjQuery(function(){jQuery(\"#StatusId\").kendoDropDownList({\"change\":statusChanged,\"select\":statusSelect,\"dataBound\":statusDataBound,\"dataSource\":{\"transport\":{\"read\":{\"url\":\"/Admin/OrderData/ReadOrderStatuses\"},\"prefix\":\"\"},\"schema\":{\"errors\":\"Errors\"}},\"dataTextField\":\"name\",\"template\":\"# if(data.disabled){# \\u003cspan class=\\u0027k-state-default tbd\\u0027\\u003e\\u003cp\\u003e#: data.name #\\u003c/p\\u003e\\u003c/span\\u003e # } else { # \\u003cspan class=\\u0027k-state-default selectableItem\\u0027\\u003e\\u003cp\\u003e#: data.name #\\u003c/p\\u003e\\u003c/span\\u003e# } # \",\"dataValueField\":\"id\"});});\r\n\u003c/script\u003e\r\n\u003c/div\u003e\u003cspan class=\"field-validation-valid\" id=\"StatusId_validationMessage\"\u003e\u003c/span\u003e"},{"title":"Faktura","headerAttributes":{"style":"white-space: normal;","data-column-data-type":"dropdown","data-dropdown-json":"[{\u0026quot;id\u0026quot;:true,\u0026quot;name\u0026quot;:\u0026quot;Z fakturą\u0026quot;},{\u0026quot;id\u0026quot;:false,\u0026quot;name\u0026quot;:\u0026quot;Bez faktury\u0026quot;}]","data-field":"InvoiceChecked","data-title":"Faktura"},"width":"50px","template":"#= InvoiceChecked? \u0027Tak\u0027 : \u0027Nie\u0027 #","field":"InvoiceChecked","filterable":{"messages":{"info":"Pokaż tylko","isTrue":"z fakturą","isFalse":"bez faktury","filter":"Filtr","clear":"Wyczyść filtr","and":"oraz","or":"lub","selectValue":"-Wybierz wartość-","value":"Wartość","cancel":"Anuluj","search":"Szukaj"},"operators":{"string":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","startswith":"zaczynają się od","endswith":"kończą się na","contains":"zawierają","doesnotcontain":"nie zawierają"},"number":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","gte":"są większe lub równe","gt":"są większe niż","lte":"są mniejsze lub równe","lt":"są mniejsze niż"},"date":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","gte":"są późniejsze lub równe","gt":"są późniejsze niż","lte":"są wcześniejsze lub równe","lt":"są wcześniejsze niż"},"enums":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż"}}},"encoded":true},{"title":"Dokument","headerAttributes":{"style":"white-space: normal;"},"template":"# if (StartingDocumentNumber) { # #= StartingDocumentNumber # \u003cbr /\u003e # } # #= createButtonDocument(StoreOrderId, DocumentButton, DocumentButtonInfo, ConflictType) #"},{"title":"Magazyn","headerAttributes":{"data-field":"Warehouse","data-title":"Magazyn"},"hidden":true,"width":"50px","field":"Warehouse","sortable":false,"filterable":false,"encoded":true},{"title":"Błędy","headerAttributes":{"data-field":"Errors","data-title":"Błędy"},"hidden":true,"width":"35px","template":"# if(Errors) { # \u003ca data-toggle=\u0027tooltip\u0027 class=\u0027tooltip-Help order-tooltip-errors\u0027 data-content=\u0027#: Errors #\u0027 data-placement=\u0027left\u0027 data-trigger=\u0027click\u0027\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027k-icon custom-icon-warning\u0027\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/a\u003e  #} # ","field":"Errors","sortable":false,"filterable":false,"encoded":true},{"title":"Zaakceptowane","headerAttributes":{"data-column-data-type":"dropdown","data-dropdown-json":"[{\u0026quot;id\u0026quot;:true,\u0026quot;name\u0026quot;:\u0026quot;Zaakceptowane\u0026quot;},{\u0026quot;id\u0026quot;:false,\u0026quot;name\u0026quot;:\u0026quot;Niezaakceptowane\u0026quot;}]","data-field":"Accepted","data-title":"Zaakceptowane"},"template":"# if(Accepted) { # Tak # } else {# \u003cbutton class=\u0027k-button k-button-icontext\u0027 onclick=\u0027acceptOrder(#:StoreOrderId# );\u0027\u003e\u003cspan class=\u0027k-icon custom-icon-accept\u0027\u003e\u003c/span\u003eZaakceptuj\u003c/button\u003e #}#","field":"Accepted","filterable":{"messages":{"info":"Pokaż tylko","isTrue":"zaakceptowane","isFalse":"niezaakceptowane","filter":"Filtr","clear":"Wyczyść filtr","and":"oraz","or":"lub","selectValue":"-Wybierz wartość-","value":"Wartość","cancel":"Anuluj","search":"Szukaj"},"operators":{"string":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","startswith":"zaczynają się od","endswith":"kończą się na","contains":"zawierają","doesnotcontain":"nie zawierają"},"number":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","gte":"są większe lub równe","gt":"są większe niż","lte":"są mniejsze lub równe","lt":"są mniejsze niż"},"date":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","gte":"są późniejsze lub równe","gt":"są późniejsze niż","lte":"są wcześniejsze lub równe","lt":"są wcześniejsze niż"},"enums":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż"}}},"encoded":true},{"title":"Błędy synchronizacji","headerAttributes":{"data-column-data-type":"dropdown","data-dropdown-json":"[{\u0026quot;id\u0026quot;:true,\u0026quot;name\u0026quot;:\u0026quot;Archiwalne\u0026quot;},{\u0026quot;id\u0026quot;:false,\u0026quot;name\u0026quot;:\u0026quot;Bieżące\u0026quot;}]","data-field":"Disabled","data-title":"Błędy synchronizacji"},"hidden":true,"width":"35px","template":"#= createDisabledInfo(Disabled, StoreOrderId) #","field":"Disabled","filterable":{"messages":{"info":"Pokaż tylko","isTrue":"archiwalne","isFalse":"bieżące","filter":"Filtr","clear":"Wyczyść filtr","and":"oraz","or":"lub","selectValue":"-Wybierz wartość-","value":"Wartość","cancel":"Anuluj","search":"Szukaj"},"operators":{"string":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","startswith":"zaczynają się od","endswith":"kończą się na","contains":"zawierają","doesnotcontain":"nie zawierają"},"number":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","gte":"są większe lub równe","gt":"są większe niż","lte":"są mniejsze lub równe","lt":"są mniejsze niż"},"date":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","gte":"są późniejsze lub równe","gt":"są późniejsze niż","lte":"są wcześniejsze lub równe","lt":"są wcześniejsze niż"},"enums":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż"}}},"encoded":true},{"title":"Szczegóły","attributes":{"alwaysShow":"True"},"width":"50px","template":"#= OrderGridService.createButtonMoreInfo(StoreOrderId) #"}],"pageable":{"autoBind":false,"buttonCount":10,"messages":{"allPages":"Wszystko","display":"Wyświetlanie elementów {0} - {1} z {2}","empty":"Brak danych","page":"Strona","of":"z {0}","itemsPerPage":"na stronę","first":"Idź do pierwszej strony","previous":"Przejdź do poprzedniej strony","next":"Przejdź do następnej strony","last":"Przejdź do ostatniej strony","refresh":"Odśwież","morePages":"Więcej stron"}},"sortable":true,"filterable":{"messages":{"info":"Pokaż wiersze o wartościach, które","isTrue":"prawda","isFalse":"fałsz","filter":"Filtr","clear":"Wyczyść filtr","and":"oraz","or":"lub","selectValue":"-Wybierz wartość-","value":"Wartość","cancel":"Anuluj","search":"Szukaj"},"operators":{"string":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","startswith":"zaczynają się od","endswith":"kończą się na","contains":"zawierają","doesnotcontain":"nie zawierają"},"number":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","gte":"są większe lub równe","gt":"są większe niż","lte":"są mniejsze lub równe","lt":"są mniejsze niż"},"date":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż","gte":"są późniejsze lub równe","gt":"są późniejsze niż","lte":"są wcześniejsze lub równe","lt":"są wcześniejsze niż"},"enums":{"eq":"są równe","neq":"są inne niż"}}},"resizable":true,"reorderable":true,"scrollable":{"height":"auto"},"editable":{"confirmation":"Czy na pewno chcesz usunąć ten rekord?","confirmDelete":"Usuń","cancelDelete":"Anuluj","mode":"incell","template":null,"create":true,"update":true,"destroy":true},"messages":{"noRecords":"No records available."},"autoBind":false,"dataSource":{"type":(function(){if(kendo.data.transports['aspnetmvc-ajax']){return 'aspnetmvc-ajax';} else{throw new Error('The kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js script is not included.');}})(),"transport":{"read":{"url":"/Admin/OrderData/ReadOrders","data":productName},"prefix":"","update":{"url":"/Admin/OrderData/SetOrderStatus","data":addAntiForgeryToken}},"pageSize":10,"page":1,"total":0,"serverPaging":true,"serverSorting":true,"serverFiltering":true,"serverGrouping":true,"serverAggregates":true,"filter":[],"requestEnd":refresh,"sync":syncHandler,"schema":{"data":"Data","total":"Total","errors":"Errors","model":{"id":"Id","fields":{"Id":{"editable":false,"type":"number"},"StoreOrderId":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"UserName":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"UserEmail":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"CreateDate":{"editable":false,"type":"date"},"PaymentCompleted":{"editable":false,"type":"boolean"},"PaymentDate":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"ProductsPrice":{"editable":false,"type":"number"},"TotalPrice":{"editable":false,"type":"number"},"DeliveryWayName":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"Status":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"StatusId":{"type":"number"},"StatusChangeDate":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"StartingDocumentNumber":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"Errors":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"DocumentButton":{"editable":false,"type":"number"},"DocumentButtonInfo":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"InvoiceChecked":{"editable":false,"type":"boolean"},"Accepted":{"editable":false,"type":"boolean"},"HasDocument":{"editable":false,"type":"boolean"},"Warehouse":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"Disabled":{"editable":false,"type":"boolean"},"CanCreatePackage":{"editable":false,"type":"boolean"},"DeliveryType":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"PackageReferenceNumber":{"editable":false,"type":"string"},"PackCancelled":{"editable":false,"type":"boolean"},"ConflictType":{"editable":false,"type":"number","defaultValue":null},"CanGetLabel":{"editable":false,"type":"boolean"}}}}}});});
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**
It is enough to add template to dropdown in callback function *statusFilter* (UI argument). It is function in which we define Filter data Source, apperance and filter options.

```
function statusFilter(element) {
    element.kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: "/OrderData/ReadOrderStatuses"
            }
        },
        template: "# if(data.disabled) { # <span class='k-state-default tbd'><p>#: data.name #</p></span> # } else { # <span class='k-state-default selectableItem'><p>#: data.name #</p></span> # } #",
        optionLabel: "--Select Status--",
        dataValueField: "id",
        dataTextField: "name",
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the whole template in `<TEXT> </TEXT>` for Razor

```
    .Filterable(filterable => filterable
        .Cell(configurator =>
        {
             var clientTemplate = 
@"# if(data.disabled) { #
<span class='k-state-default tbd'><p>#: data.name #</p></span>
# } else { #
<span class='k-state-default    '><p>#: data.name #</p></span>
# } #";
             configurator.Template($"<TEXT>{clientTemplate}</TEXT>");
        })
        .UI("statusFilter")
        .Extra(false)
    )
```

Comment: I cannot use interpolated string due to my C# version. I tried Template("<TEXT>" + clientTemplate + "</TEXT>") but I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: Try simplifying the template and look at the code in the browsers "developer tools" debugger. What happens when you have only `clientTemplate = "# debugger; #";` ? while Tools window is open.  Does source code debugger stop in the virtual method the kendo template compiler creates ? If it does, build up the template by adding more code until you find where the error gets thrown.

Comment: I get error: "unexpected token". Code in web browser: "ui":statusFilter,"cell":{"template":# debugger; #}},"encoded":true,